# Groovy and Hibernate - Performant Queries in one to Many relationships

Tags: performance, hibernate, groovy

I have inherited a rather complex groovy application and am trying to understand how I can better solve some of the nasty query patterns that presently exist.

Simply, I have something like:

```
Class A {
    User user
    Bravo bravo
    static hasMany = [foo: Foo, bar: Long]
}

Class Foo {
    User user
    Delta delta
    static belongsTo = [a: A]
    static hasMany = [woo: Woo]
}

Class Woo {
    User user
    Alpha alpha
    static belongsTo = [foo: Foo]
}
```

I'm attempting to do `A.findAllByUser(user)` which is returning me a `<List>A`, however when I start itering over that list I'm hitting hundreds of queries that are further building out `bravo` and `foo`.

I attempted to add `Foo fetch:"join"` to the Foo class and `Woo fetch: "join"` to the Woo class, however this means that EVERY query that touches these two will always make those queries (and still doesn't solve the hundreds of queries hitting `bravo`.

I'm a rather novice when it comes to using HQL, however this is causing some serious issues with performance and large queries at scale.  Is there a better way to tackle this problem (and hopefully avoid hundreds of select queries)?

Comment: When you iterate through `A` you are also reading something from `A.foo` or `A.bravo`? Even `toString` can cause these fields to be read and thus, be loaded by hibernate

Comment: is this a groovy or grails/gorm app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using GORM (which is the ORM used by the Grails framework).

To solve your problem, you need to decide what your most common use case is. If you want to keep fetching lazily by default, you can locally change the fetch strategy when you need to: `A.findAllByUser(user, [fetch: join])`.

If on the other hand you want to make eager fetching the default but want to disable it locally, I believe you should use `lazy: false` instead of `fetch: join` in your domain class because it is safer with one-to-many associations. And you should be able to disable it for any given query (e.g. `A.findAllByUser(user, [lazy: true])`.

See [here](http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#_altering_fetch_strategy_for_a_query).